# Solving a sudoku in Scala

Tags: scala, sudoku

I'm learning Scala (and am new to functional programming).
I have created a sudoku checker (which will later on be a game where you can actually set numbers in a sudoku, and maybe an automatic sudoku solver).

Checking rows and columns if they are correct works fine and in a functional oriented way.

Though, checking for a 3x3 square to be correct, I've written a pretty ugly method (see below in my code).

Any tips about how I can maybe solve this easier and more Scala'ish?

I've found the methods .slice(from, until), .splitAt(until), .sliding(size, step) and tried to do something with 'transpose' again. Though I cant' come up with a working (more) functional way to do this.

```
class Sudoku(){
  val sudoku =
    Array(
      Array(0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 2, 6),
      Array(3, 8, 9, 4, 2, 0, 1, 5, 7),
      Array(4, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9),
      Array(0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 0, 0, 4),
      Array(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0),
      Array(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0),
      Array(0, 0, 1, 9, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0),
      Array(9, 3, 5, 6, 4, 0, 8, 0, 1),
      Array(0, 0, 2, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5)
  )

  def checkSudoku(): Unit ={
    println(check(sudoku))
  }

  private def check(sudoku: Array[Array[Int]]): Boolean = checkRows(sudoku) && checkCols(sudoku) && checkSquars(sudoku)
  private def checkCols(sudoku: Array[Array[Int]]) = checkRows(sudoku.transpose)
  private def checkRows(sudoku: Array[Array[Int]]): Boolean = sudoku.forall(row => checkRow(row))
  private def checkRow(row: Array[Int]): Boolean = row.distinct.length == row.length


  private def checkSquars(sudoku: Array[Array[Int]]): Boolean ={
    val squared : Array[Array[Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int](1,3)

    for(i <- 0 to (sudoku.length-1)/3) {
      for(o <- 0 to (sudoku(i).length-1)/3) {
        squared((i*3)+o) = sudoku(0+(i*3)).slice(0+(o*3), 3+(o*3)) ++ sudoku(1+(i*3)).slice(0+(o*3), 3+(o*3)) ++ sudoku(2+(i*3)).slice(0+(o*3), 3+(o*3))
      }
    }
    squared.forall(row => checkRow(row))
  }
}

val sudoku = new Sudoku()
sudoku.checkSudoku();
```

Comment: Where's the checkRow method?

Comment: below the checkRows() method

private def checkRow(row: Array[Int]): Boolean = row.distinct.length == row.length

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (slightly brainfucky) way to do the checkSquares method:

```
val rowBlocks = sudoku.grouped(3).toArray
def splitRow(row: Array[Int]) = row.grouped(3).toArray

val squares = rowBlocks.map( block => block.map(splitRow).transpose)
```

You should convince yourself that `squares` is a 3x3 array of the squares of the sudoku. Now you just need to check the condition:

```
squares.forall(_.forall(sq => sq.flatten.distinct.length == sq.flatten.length))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to get all the squares as lines. I tried to make it more readable:

```
  val squareSize = 3
  val boardSize = sudoku.length

  val squareLines = for {
    rowStart <- List.range(0, boardSize, squareSize)
    colStart <- List.range(0, boardSize, squareSize)
  } yield {
    List.range(0, squareSize).flatMap {
      i =>
        sudoku(rowStart + i).slice(colStart, colStart + squareSize)
    }
  }
```

You can then check `squareLines` with `checkRow` like you are doing in your method.

The `rowStart` and `colStart` pairs can also be generated using `combinations(2)` on the `List.range`, but I figured it would be too verbose for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I started with using list / array to manage the puzzle but much later, I find using a map is better.

Next, use Array[Set[Int]] instead of Array[Array[Int]] to use Set to remove duplicates in the group.

I included the function `conflict(...)` to check for conflicts. You can use it for your reference. As I continue to make changes (i.e. I am not using this function any more as I have other ways to achieve the same purpose but it served its purpose) and quickly putting this answer together, they may not compile. I hope you can get the idea and give me a shout if you need help.

```
val digits = ('1' to '9').mkString
val alphas = ('A' to 'I').mkString

def cross(rows: String, cols: String) = for {
  row <- rows
  col <- cols
} yield {"" + row + col}

val verticals = digits.map(d => cross(alphas, d.toString))

val horizontals = alphas.map(a => cross(a.toString, digits))

val blocks = for {
  rowBlk <- alphas.grouped(3)
  colBlk <- digits.grouped(3)
} yield (cross(rowBlk, colBlk))

val all = horizontals ++ verticals ++ blocks

def everyone = cross(alphas, digits).foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Set[Set[Int]]])((m,a) => m + (a -> (all.filter(_.contains(a)).map(_.toSet).toSet)))

def conflict(cell: String, solution: Map[String, Set[Int]]) = 
  if (everyone(cell)
    .map(cells => cells.toList.foldLeft(List.empty[Int])((chars, c) => 
      if (solution(c).size > 1) chars else chars ++ solution(c).toList))
        .forall(xs => xs.size == xs.distinct.size)) solution else Map.empty
```